# Join between databases in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Hello I am making join between 2 databases, they are in identical table structure:
Two databases `db1` with table `weather1` and `db2` with table `weather2`

```
 $weather = DB::connection('db1')->table('weather1')
    ->whereBetween('recordtime', $dateScope)
    ->join('db2.weather2', 'db2.weather2.recordtime', '=', 'recordtime')
    ->selectRaw('recordtime,tempout,db2.map1_weather2.tempout as tempout2')
    ->orderBy('recordtime', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

The error is:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "db2.weather2" does not exist LINE 1:
```

I did named the datebases in `.env` and `database.php`

How to get it work?

Comment: You mean the table `weather2` is on a different database called **db2** ?

Comment: Yes , Two databases db1 with table weather1 and db2 with table weather2

Comment: Try removing the `DB::connection` and use your connection labels as prefixes (e.g. `db1.weather1`, `db2.weather2`).

Comment: How the other way is with Eloquent?